# Checking if a column name exists in another dataset

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have two different datasets and I am trying to check if a column name has a duplicate column name in another data set. For example:

```
V1    V2    V3
1     2      3
```

as one data set and

```
V4    V6    V1   V2
NA    NA    NA   NA
```

And I am trying to make it so the second data set is like this

```
V4    V6    V1   V2
NA    NA    1   NA
```

where only the minimum value in the original data set copies over, if that makes since. I have tried using this function:

```
if(ncol((Session1t[grep(temp1, names(Session1t))])) != 0)
```

But this is not working. It returns the same value regardless of what is input. After entering the if statement I then work to copy only the column that I want over,and I have that figured out, I just cannot get the if statement to work effectively.

Comment: Why in the second data frame `V2` is `NA`?

Comment: Why is only `V1` copied but not `V2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` and `%in%` to match column names and replace `NA` with 1.

```
# Create example data frame D1
D1 <- read.table(text = "V1    V2    V3
1     2      3",
                 header = TRUE)

# Create example data frame D2
D2 <- read.table(text = "V4    V6    V1   V2
NA    NA    NA   NA",
                 header = TRUE)

# Replace NA to 1 if column names match
D2[1, ] <- ifelse(names(D2) %in% names(D1), 1, NA)
D2
#   V4 V6 V1 V2
# 1 NA NA  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or another option is `intersect`

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
df2[nm1] <- df1[nm1]
```